# How do I move all the file paths in an array to one directory

Tags: c#, file, system.io.file, system.io.directory

This is what I have tried

```
string[] filestomove = new string[] {"text.txt", "never.json", "gonna.dll", "giveyou.exe", "up.png"};
string[] dirstomove = new string[] {"never gonna", "let you down", "never gonna", "run around", "and desert you"};
foreach(string filename in filestomove)
{
    if(File.Exists(filename)) {
        File.Copy(filename, path, true);
    }
}

foreach(string dirname in dirstomove)
{
    if(Directory.Exists(dirname)) {
        Directory.Move(dirname, path);
    }
}
```

However, it didnt work for me for some reason, it gave me an error. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What "error" did you get?

Comment: Technically your code does not try to move file paths but filenames (your `filestomove` array has no path)

Comment: Did you just [rickroll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) SO? Love the file and directory names

Comment: System.IO.IOException: The target file '<path>' is a directory, not a file.

Comment: @Markus Possibly a `StrangersToLoveException` . OP: Are you trying to flatten the contents of nested directories into a single directory? If so, what do you plan to do with filename conflicts (e.g. `c:\folder\subfolder\A.txt` and `c:\folder\subfolder2\A.txt` move to `c:\flatfolder\A.txt`)

Comment: @Tal You need to specify the full path of the target file when moving - so you need to append the target filename to `path`

Comment: @Martin Never expected to be RickRolled from StackOverflow

Comment: Can someone **answer** the question? Its just a little bit clearer. Also, include some code to help me.

Comment: append the filename to `destinationpath`. you are just giving the directory name and not the filename in the destination folder... The documentation clearly says...  The name of the destination file. This cannot be a directory.

Comment: @Tal When you answer _my_ question, I'll try to answer yours. Why do you have to answer mine first? So I can understand your question, of course.

Comment: @Llama I plan to overwrite any files that are named the same. Also, I am not moving any files that have the same name into the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a full path to write to:

```cs
string[] filestomove = new string[] {"text.txt", "never.json", "gonna.dll", "giveyou.exe", "up.png"};
string[] dirstomove = new string[] {"never gonna", "let you down", "never gonna", "run around", "and desert you"};
foreach(string filename in filestomove)
{
    if(File.Exists(filename)) 
    {
        // from c:\folder\A.txt, extract A.txt
        string name = Path.GetFileName(filename);

        // combine that with path to get c:\newfolder\A.txt
        string targetFileName = Path.Combine(path, name);
     
        // Move the file
        File.Copy(filename, targetFileName, true);
    }
}

foreach(string dirname in dirstomove)
{
    if(Directory.Exists(dirname)) 
    {
        // From c:\folder\somefolder get somefolder
        string name = new DirectoryInfo(dirname).Name;
        
        // Combine that with path to get c:\newfolder\somefolder
        string targetDirectory = Path.Combine(path, name);

        // Move the directory
        Directory.Move(dirname, targetDirectory);
    }
}
```